# Entity Framework to update the entries in the database table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5

I am using Entity Framework 5.0 to add the entries in the SQL Database. The logic for adding works fine i am using context.tableEntity.add() method
I don't find any update method, I saw Sqlquery() but if i have to manually construct the SQL and run it the entity framework wont be used to its full potential.
How can i update the entries in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is to attach the entity to your context, set the state to modified, and then call .SaveChanges().

This MSDN article should help get you pointed in the right direction.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx